# Solve the equation: $-u''=f(x), 0<x<1, u(0)=u(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Solve the equation using green's function $-u''=f(x), 0<x<1, u(0)=u(1)=0$

I got the solution as being $u(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}(x-1)f(x)+xf(x)(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-1+x$.

Which is wrong. Can anyone see where i went wrong?

Comment: There's no way to simplify further than the relation involving the integral unless you know what $f$ is. I haven't checked carefully to see that that much is right, but yeah, there's no way to simplify any more.

Comment: So you can't take the f(x) out of the integral?

Comment: As you wrote it, you would be able to, but I think you have an error in how the integral is set up.

Comment: Keep in mind here that you can do this without the Green's function to just get the answer. Simply select a particular second antiderivative of $-f$, call it $F$, now $u(x)=F(x)+ax+b$ so $b=-F(0)$ and $a=-F(1)+F(0)$. You see $f$ doesn't show up anywhere except under an integral sign.

Comment: What book is it and what page ?

Comment: Just to attach a more explicit formula to what I said, define $F(x)=\int_0^x \int_0^y -f(z) dz dy$, then $b=0$ and $a=\int_0^1 \int_0^y f(z) dz dy$ so that $u(x)=\int_0^x \int_0^y -f(z) dz dy + x \left ( \int_0^1 \int_0^y f(z) dz dy \right )$. You can think of this as the result of using the Green's function and then applying integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next to last formula is wrong, it should have $f(s)$ instead of $f(x)$, that is,
$$
u(x)=\int_0^1G(x,s)f(s)\,ds=-\int_0^x (1-x)sf(s)\,ds-\int_x^1 x(1-s)f(s)\,ds
$$
Without knowing $f$ no further evaluation of the integrals is possible.

Comment: is the reason for the negative in integral because (x-1) into (1-x)

Comment: Yes. It is just a question of taste to decide to have the factors all positive.